# When "ORDER BY" on an IFNULL function, send nulls to end

Tags: mysql, null, sql-order-by

The following ORDER BY statement, only

```
SELECT * FROM x 
  LEFT JOIN y ON y.x_id = x.id
  ORDER BY IFNULL(x.a, y.a) ASC
```

I'd like any NULLs to be at the end of the resulting list. Right now they're at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do an explicit comparison.  However, I'm not sure *what* you want to be `null`.  Here is a guess:

```
order by (x.a is NULL and y.a is NULL) desc, coalesce(x.a, y.a)
```

Comment: Basically what I want is to order by x.a first, but if that doesn't exist, order by y.a, and if neither exist i want the record to be at the bottom.

Comment: Actually, I think we're halfway there, this appears to work:
`order by (x.a is NULL and y.a is NULL), IFNULL(x.a, y.a) ASC`